# Play framework 2: implicit values in view

Tags: scala, view, playframework-2.0, implicit

I need to pass some variable implicitly in url creation in views.

I have action in controller:

```
class HomeController extends Controller{

  def index(implicit lang: Lang) = Action.async { implicit request => {
      Future[Result] {
        Ok(views.html.home.index(lang))
      }
    }

    ...
  }
```

Here is snippet of **index.scala.html**:

```
@()(implicit lang: Lang)
@main("Home page") {
     <ul>
        <li><a href="@routes.HomeController.index()"><span>Home</span></a>
     ...
     </ul>
}
```

But I have compile error at **@routes.HomeController.index()**, **not enough arguments for method**

Why is it an error? How can I implicit pass variables in url creation?

Comment: Remove the parentheses from the reverse routing call: `@routes.HomeController.index`. Though you might end up with problems trying to use implicit `Lang` on the `index` method.

Comment: I've tried this, still not working. "missing arguments for method index in class ReverseHomeController"

Comment: keep parens and try `def index()(implicit lang: Lang)`

Comment: Still not working.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
class HomeController extends Controller {
 def index = Action.async { implicit request => {
      Future[Result] {
        Ok(views.html.home.index)
      }
    }
    ...
  }
```

Do not explictly pass lang param into function . Play `Controller` contains implict conversion from request to lang, with this lang will be automagically provided into your view.

Comment: I have to use lang param in index method, because I have defined routes like this: GET /$lang<ka|en> controllers.HomeController.index(lang: play.api.i18n.Lang).   Basically, I don't need to pass lang param in index method, I just need part in route /<ka|en>, (Actual language resolver is handler in filter, this <ka|en> I need just for routes). But wihtout /$lang... it does not work, and if I provide $lang in route pattern, than I should pass it to index method, otherwise I'm getting compiler error

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your problem, but if you want to keep lang param in method then later you need to rednder view this way         `Ok(views.html.home.index()(lang))`